# R -shiny- DT: how to update col filters

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to use DT to allow the users to modify a dataset.
However, when the factor cols change (by adding or removing a factor level) the corresponding table filter remains unchanged.
In the following example: if I change a Species, the new Species does not appear in the filter dropdown list.
Is there a workaround?
Many thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

library(dplyr)

iris2=iris %>% group_by(Species)  %>% filter(Petal.Length==max(Petal.Length))

  

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput("table"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderDT({
    
    DT::datatable(iris2, filter = "top", editable=T)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to feed the changes back into the DT data to get the filters to update. I did this by creating a changeable reactiveVal that DT reads. The next step is to watch for changes to your table and push those changes to the reactiveVal. It's a bit trickier for a factor because you may have to add a new factor level to the column. Another catch is that the edited value may not conform to the original class, so you can force it to match.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

iris2=iris %>% group_by(Species)  %>% filter(Petal.Length==max(Petal.Length))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput("table")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  iris_rv <- reactiveVal(iris2)         # keep live iris2 table in this reactiveVal
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(iris_rv(), filter = "top", editable=T)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, { # watch for edits
    req(input$table_cell_edit)
    
    iris_tmp <- iris_rv()               # transfer to simple variable for easier access
    old_val <- iris_tmp[input$table_cell_edit$row,input$table_cell_edit$col] %>% unlist()
    new_val <- input$table_cell_edit$value
    
    if (class(old_val) == "factor") {   # deal with new factor levels
      old_col <- iris_tmp %>% pull(input$table_cell_edit$col)
      new_col <- factor(old_col, levels = union(levels(old_col), new_val))
      iris_tmp[,input$table_cell_edit$col] <- new_col
    } else {                            # otherwise simply force new value to correct class
      class(new_val) <- class(old_val)
    }
    
    iris_tmp[input$table_cell_edit$row,input$table_cell_edit$col] <- new_val
    iris_rv(iris_tmp)                   # overwrite iris_rv with updated values
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reactiveValues` to get the `DT` to update on change and I used validate to make sure that numbers are correctly provided, `clean` is where the magic happens, it checks if the column is a `factor` if so check if the value is a level then if not add it.

```r
library(DT)

iris2 = iris %>% group_by(Species)  %>% filter(Petal.Length==max(Petal.Length))
# get the classes of the columns
types <- sapply(iris2, class)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput("table"))
  )
)
types <- sapply(iris2, class)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('table')
  RV <- reactiveValues(data = iris2)

  output$table = DT::renderDT({
    RV$data
  }, filter = "top", editable=T)

  observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
    validate(
      need(check_coercibility(input$table_cell_edit$value, types[input$table_cell_edit$col]), "Please enter valid data")
    )
    RV$data <- clean(RV$data, input$table_cell_edit$value, input$table_cell_edit$row, input$table_cell_edit$col)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}
check_coercibility <- function(x, type){
    if(type == "numeric") {
        suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(x)))
    } else T
}
clean <- function(df, x, nrow, ncol, type=types[[ncol]]){
    col <- df[[ncol]]
    df[nrow, ncol] <- if(type=="factor"){
        if(! x %in% levels(col)) df[[ncol]] <- factor( col, levels=c(levels(col), x))
        x
    } else if(type=="numeric"){
        as.numeric(x)
    } else if(type=="logical"){
        as.logical(x)
    } else x
    df
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I cannot decide about who to award with the poins based on the solutions, since I think they are based on the same concept. So, first come first served, seems about right to me.