# R datatable's editable functionality incorporated with rowtotal and dynamic column calculation

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I am trying to produce a user interactive table like [Target table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHRzX.png)

The yellow columns represent editable columns, white ones can't be edited, and they work in following fashion

- User updates column B and allocates 100% of distribution among the three rows(40,35,25 in this case). A total is shown in footer to help user identify correct allocation of 100%
- Column A updates in backend by multiplying each % with a predetermined number(1000 in this case). A total is shown, which would be 1000 if user entered % correctly
- User then enters values in column C. No total is necessary here
- Column D is then calculated in backend as a product of column A and column C

Is this achievable by any simple means?
I also then want to reuse this table for more calculations since this is the input prompt

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do most or all of this with the tools you tagged but it won't be simple:

- The DT package will not do all of this for you: you will also have to use reactivity.
- This link discusses working with edited values in DT, providing an idea of the level of difficulty to expect: [R -shiny- DT: how to update col filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326133/r-shiny-dt-how-to-update-col-filters/65362668#65362668).
- In addition to what you see in the example, you want to add formatting, a totals row, and only allow editing of some columns, which will require more work.